# Problems importing SAP Commerce 2105 into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sap-commerce-cloud

I have successfully upgraded my localhost copy of SAP Commerce 2005 to 2105, and I'm now in the process of importing the 2105 platform into my Eclipse IDE. This import process runs for a long time and eventually errors out with the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I've tried increasing heap size for Eclipse multiple times, but I still end up running out of memory. I'm using the Hybris/Eclipse plugin to do this.

It appears that the smartedit module has significantly increased in size and seems to be the culprit in getting the platform to load.

I've read that it's not possible to load the 2105 platform into Eclipse with the smartedit projects included, and I've also read that upgrading the version of the Hybris/Eclipse plugin does not help either.

What is everyone else doing to solve this problem? I've tried several times loading individual projects, making sure to exclude any project with the name 'smartedit' in it, but it still runs for a long time and then exits with the out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Without stacktrace hard to say what is going on your PC. MAYBE that issue is same to already raised on github.com on plugin repository.

https://github.com/SAP/hybris-commerce-eclipse-plugin/issues/99

I have tested that and closed. There is solution proposed to that particular case. Maybe will work out with yours

Comment: i tried importing using plugin for hybris still same issue. The import is stuck at smartedittools for 2105. Can please provide steps to be performed

Comment: Another thought. Can you follow steps on SAP Help page related to importing as gradle project? https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/04e41b4d3354415cbb54b07592a8596d.html

for 2105 it is required to have Gradle 6.x. with SAP Commerce Cloud 2205 you can go with Gradle 7